# How to have an image render before alt text

Tags: docusaurus

I'm working on a documentation site and noticed that the images have a very slight delay. I realized it's because the alt text shows up before the image renders.

Is there a way to hide the alt text before the image appears?[alt-text-shows-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgLet.jpg)

I want the image load to look a little cleaner to the users. If there's something that I could do on my end it would be appreciated. In the docusaurus blog I noticed the same thing happens with the image, I see the alt text before the image appears https://docusaurus.io/blog
At first I thought it was just on my end, but my peer noticed it on his machine as well.

I had the images in a folder with the .md document, then moved them to the static folder as it was suggested on the docusaurus website. The delay still persists even when moved to the correct folders.